# GTK+ 3.0 and GNOME 3 Programming! Any Blog or Book or Tutorial?

Tags: blogs, gnome, gtk3, gnome-3

I am new to gtk and gnome programming and like to study GTK+ 3.0 and Gnome 3 programming. Since both of these are recent APIs, I can't find a good tutorial or blog post about these topics. The books I found on GTK+ or GNOME programming are very old ones. So I decided to start with the latest gtk tutorial at http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/ which currently happened to be about GTK+ 2.90.7.

I need your help to find any **tutorial** or **blogs** or any **book** which cover **GTK+ 3.0 or GNOME 3 programming topics**. Would you please share any links that you know about these topics and thank you in advance.

Comment: The best park of GTK+ 3 and GTK+ 4 is there still aren't any books.  What a wasted resource.  Almost 11 years since this post and still no book.  I don't think it's worth getting in to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you need to start looking [here](http://developer.gnome.org/). Second, what was said before is kinda right, there are books about Gtk+ 2.x and you could apply almost everything you learn to Gtk+ 3.x programming. I started by using Gtk+ 2.x and a few time later Gtk+ 3.x went out. I changed to the new version, migrated my old code, and that was how I learn to use Gtk+ 3.x, although have to say that is a process of always learning with Gtk/Glib based programming.
My recommendation: Learn Gtk+ 2.x there's some books, and some tutorials around. I remember [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597931). And your other tool, main tool to is to read Gnome Project code, code from nautilus, gnome-control-center, gnome-utils, etc., almost everything basic you want to make your app do, there's already done by some Gnome module.

Answer (score 6):

I've just seen this book came out: "GNOME 3 Application Development Beginner's Guide"

http://www.packtpub.com/gnome-3-application-development-beginners-guide/book

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [10-minute tutorials](http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/) on developer.gnome.org. They are designed for GTK 3.0. (Although really not much has changed in the basics between GTK 2 and 3.)

Answer (score 5):

`Gtk+ Tutorials & Resources`

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=72088=GTK3+with+CSS#p72088

Scroll down to the links in `gtkforums.com Index: Gtk+3.x with CSS`

I suggest starting in: `Intro and first program`

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=72088=GTK3+with+CSS#p72088

Also under the section `GTK+ Programming Tutorials "GUI Toolkit"` you'll find:

`Official GTK+3.x "Getting Started with GTK+"`

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html

`Official GTK+3.x "Tutorials, code samples, and platform demos in C"`

http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/3.5/c.html.en

Also: `GNOME University Project`
http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=178162

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you start with GTK+ 2.x ? I used GTK+ 2.x for my project and changed it to GTK3+ lately. Most changes are object fields which became private and now have to be accessed via methods. Another big change in GTK3+ is the depreacation of GdkGC. Instead of GdkGC you now have to use Cairo, but cairo is already available in GTK 2.x. In my opinion moving from GTK+ 2.x to GTK3+ at a latter stadium is not a big issue. And since GTK3+ is still pretty new it is not fully supported everywhere. I.e: the latest LTS Ubuntu is 10.10 which does not run GTK3+. Neither is the GTK3+ for Windows fully supported yet.